# Getting a refresh token from OAuth.io through REST API

Tags: c#, .net, oauth.io

I'm trying to get a refresh token for Google through Oauth.io but I'm having trouble finding the endpoint to send the code to. I'm using C# so I can't use the server-side SDK. I've also looked at [Getting refresh tokens from Google with OAuth.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759138/getting-refresh-tokens-from-google-with-oauth-io) but that answer doesn't help me get the actual refresh token. I've looked at their [server-side flow documentation](https://oauth.io/docs/security#the-server-side-flow) which tells me I can get my refresh token at /auth/access_token but when looking at the [web API documentation](https://oauth.io/docs/api-reference/default/rest) I don't see that endpoint listed.

I've also looked at their example [here](http://docs.oauth.io/?Javascript#authorizing-the-user-with-both-front-end-and-back-end-sdks) and I don't see the endpoint they use listed on the API documentation either. It also doesn't say which key/secret to use with that request - is it the one listed for my OAuth.io app, or is it the one for my provider (in this case Google)?

Any help going forward would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just updated the documentation on docs.oauth.io, it was effectively /auth/access_token.

Take a look at the node.js SDK implementation: https://github.com/oauth-io/sdk-node/blob/master/coffee/lib/authentication.coffee#L99

The request is a `POST` on `https://oauth.io/auth/access_token` and require 3 parameters:

- `code` : the code to be exchange against the access token / refresh token
- `key` : the OAuth.io public key
- `secret` : the OAuth.io secret key

Comment: Thanks for this. I eventually went through the Node.js SDK to figure out the end point and parameters, but by that time I forgot I even posted this question so I'm glad others will be able to find it through here as well.