# OAuth.io server-side doesn't refresh Google token

Tags: php, google-api, oauth.io

At first please do not mark this as duplicated as this is related to server-side (PHP) and not to client-side as other posts.

I'm trying to refresh the token for Google API through Oauth.io. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759138/getting-refresh-tokens-from-google-with-oauth-io) and many other posts but no luck. Unfortunately Oauth.io documentation is not the best one. I don't have this problem with Twitter and Facebook only Google.

I'm getting refresh_token when I connect for the first time. Then I need to do API call once a day.

```
{
  "access_token":"xxx",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"xxx",
  "id_token":"xxx",
  "provider":"google_analytics"
}
```

The question is how to refresh Google token through Oauth.io?

The [documentation](http://docs.oauth.io/?PHP#refreshing-the-tokens) says:

> // The auth method automatically refreshes the tokens if needed
>       $request_object = $oauth->auth('facebook', array(
>         'credentials' => $credentials
>       ));

and points [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759138/getting-refresh-tokens-from-google-with-oauth-io), but it doesn't solve the problem. All it does is that I'm getting refresh_token value in response.

**UPDATE**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827359/getting-a-refresh-token-from-oauth-io-through-rest-api) post I tried to do:

```
$request_object->post('https://oauth.io/auth/access_token', array(
    'code' => 'xxx', // here I tried access_token, refresh_token
    'key' => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxx',
));
```

but all I'm getting is

```
array(4) {
  'status' =>
      string(5) "error"
  'code' =>
      int(401)
  'message' =>
      string(70) "Bearer token invalid. Follow the oauth2-token link to get a valid one!"
  'data' =>
      array(1) {
          'code' =>
              string(17) "UnauthorizedError"
      }
}
```

Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it. You can refresh the access_token using:

```
    $this->oauth = new OAuth();
    $this->oauth->initialize($publicKey, $secretKey);
```

1. $refreshedCredentials = $this->oauth->refreshCredentials($oldCredentials, true);

or

2. `$request_object = $oauth->auth('google_analytics', array(
        'credentials' => $credentials,
        'force_refresh' => true
    ));`

Both answers can be found [here](https://github.com/oauth-io/sdk-php). I had it in front of all day long and did not see it.

I prefer using 1st solution as I want to save new access_token so I can reuse it later. And you need to remember that you need to pass refresh_token, which you got with first access_token, along with last access_token to get refreshed access_token - refresh_token doesn't change until user revoke access.