# Getting refresh tokens from Google with OAuth.io JS SDK (Client side)

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, oauth.io

I am trying to get access token & refresh token using OAuth.io for Google provider. I have chosen offline for the access_type in OAuth.io.

Following is the code

```
   OAuth.popup("google", {'authorize' : { "approval_prompt" : 'force'}})
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        //handle error with err
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I am not receiving refresh_token in the response. I am getting only access_token from response.

JSON response for access token is:

```
    {
        "status": "success",
        "data": {
            "access_token": "ya29.pAGQWe3yxxxxxx",
            "token_type": "Bearer",
            "expires_in": 3600,
            "request": {
                "url": "https://www.googleapis.com",
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer {{token}}"
                }
            },
            "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzIxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "state": "Q9nfocQXJxxxx",
        "provider": "google"
    }
```

**Reference**

I have found this SO link [Getting refresh tokens from Google with OAuth.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759138/getting-refresh-tokens-from-google-with-oauth-io)
Here they have explained how to get refresh token in server side.

I want to get refresh token in client side JS.

Comment: Can you not pass it from the server to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto OAuth.io app general settings page, select **Show advanced options** and then select **Send refresh token to front-end**.

In the integrated APIs, select the **access_type** as **offline**. This will send the refresh token to front end while using the following code

```
var oauthOptions = { 'authorize' : { "approval_prompt" : "force" } };
    OAuth.popup("google", oauthOptions)
                .done(function(result) {
                    console.log("Post postProcessing");
                    console.log(result);
                })
                .fail(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first line to:

```
OAuth.popup("google", {
  'authorize' : {
    "approval_prompt" : "force",
    "access_type" : "offline"}})
```

[Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) describe how offline refresh tokens work.

Comment: I tried with access_type :"offline", refresh_token is not received in the response.

Comment: Can you try running through an OAuth request with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to see exactly what URL OAuth.io is hitting?

Comment: https://oauth.io/auth/google?k=ndXMRv8xxxxxx&d=http://localhost/&opts={"authorize":{"approval_prompt":"force","access_type":"offline"},"state":"nBGE8Rv1ufxxxxxxxx","state_type":"client"}                         This is the(decoded) URL Oauth.io JS using to open popup window

Answer (score -1):

1. Go Account Security Settings and click edit
2. https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security.
3. next to "Authorizing applications and sites". Then click "Revoke
4. Access" next to your app. The next OAuth2 request you make will
5. return a refresh_token.

You can also play with Open Oauth [Here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Comment: I have revoked permissions to my app. Then I started OAuth, I am not receiving the refresh_token